# Draw an horizontal line for a counterterm with TikZ-Feynmann

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman, feynman

I'm trying to draw the counterterm of a propagator for a scalar theory. I want to represent it with a black square. However, when I use TikZ the line is not completely horizontal. It's a probably trivial question, but I haven't resolve it.

What I wrote in latex (more or less):

```latex
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to c] {  a --[scalar] b [square dot] -- [scalar] c};

\end{document}
```

What I got (it's a little raised with the square, not completely horizontal):
[image]

(Even if I try to draw other shapes, like a crossed dot, I have the same problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome! You need to specify `layered layout`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to c,layered layout] {  a --[scalar] b [square dot] -- [scalar] c};

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unless one really wants to delve into the details of the layout mechanisms, one way to guess the "correct" algorithm is to look at the manual. On p. 21 you find

[image]

which suggests that this is the algorithm to be employed here. (Whether or not any of them is optimal for Feynman diagrams is another question.)

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked :D